# How to disable padding for first line?

Tags: html, css-selectors

http://jsfiddle.net/cgev439p/

```
p:first-line {
    color: red;
    padding-left: 0rem;
}
p {
    color: blue;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

But first line all the same has `0.5rem` padding.

How to disable padding for first line? 
(or make :not(:first-line) to have padding?)

**UPD**

@Pengcheng: [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwvq5s7u/1/) does not work

[image]

Comment: I found this: "not all properties can be used in a ruleset containing ::first-line"
scroll to see what properties can be applied: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-line/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution maybe as following:

```
p {
    color: blue;
    text-indent: -.5rem;
    padding-left: .5rem;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwvq5s7u/2/)

Comment: Doesn' Work, try his fiddle. The first line is not the first child.

Comment: Not as I see the question, but I may be wrong, let it be up to the OP.

Comment: @PoulBak, yes, you are right, I did not see the text in multiple lines. actually text-indent: .5rem hanging is the perfect solution, but non browser support this at the moment. maybe there is no pure css solution now.

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, please check my updates, hope it could help.

Comment: @Pengcheng: First child is not first line. see updated question

Comment: my last update here http://jsfiddle.net/cwvq5s7u/2/: p {
    color: blue;
    text-indent: -.5rem;
    padding-left: .5rem;
}

Comment: @Pengcheng: Do not forget to write name of person you writing to. I miss your update because of that. Just notice it when today want to answer my question with same solution